# Clojure manually find nth element in a sequence

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am a newbie to clojure (and functional programming for that matter) and I was trying to do some basic problems. I was trying to find the nth element in a sequence without recursion.

so something like

```
(my-nth '(1 2 3 4) 2) => 3
```

I had a hard time looping through the list and returning when i found the nth element. I tried a bunch of different ways and the code that I ended up with is

```
(defn sdsu-nth
 [input-list n]
 (loop [cnt n tmp-list input-list]
    (if (zero? cnt)
       (first tmp-list)
       (recur (dec cnt) (pop tmp-list)))))
```

This gives me an exception which says "cant pop from empty list"

I dont need code, but if someone could point me in the right direction it would really help!

Comment: When you say "without recursion" do you mean "with recursion"? That is what the loop/recur construct is.

Comment: I mean to say, we might want to use looping constructs but the function should not explicitly make a call to itself.

Comment: Please note that even when you use `recur` inside of `loop`, it is to emulate recursion (although it will be compiled to loop), so it's more natural to think about this construction as of recursive anonymous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the function `pop`, which has different behavior for different data structures.

```
user> (pop '(0 1 2 3 4))
(1 2 3 4)
user> (pop [0 1 2 3 4])
[0 1 2 3]
user> (pop (map identity '(0 1 2 3 4)))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentStack  clojure.lang.RT.pop (RT.java:640)
```

Furthermore, you are mixing calls to `pop` with calls to `first`. If iterating, use `peek`/`pop` or `first`/`rest` as pairs, mixing the two can lead to unexpected results. `first` / `rest` are the lowest common denominator, if you want to generalize over various sequential types, use those, and they will coerce the sequence to work if they can.

```
user> (first "hello")
\h
user> (first #{0 1 2 3 4})
0
user> (first {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2})
[:c 2]
```

With your function, replacing `pop` with `rest`, we get the expected results:

```
user> (defn sdsu-nth
        [input-list n]
        (loop [cnt n tmp-list input-list]
              (if (zero? cnt)
                  (first tmp-list)
                (recur (dec cnt) (rest tmp-list)))))

#'user/sdsu-nth
user> (sdsu-nth (map identity '(0 1 2 3 4)) 2)
2
user> (sdsu-nth [0 1 2 3 4] 2)
2
user> (sdsu-nth '(0 1 2 3 4) 2)
2
user> (sdsu-nth "01234" 2)
\2
```

Answer (score 4):

given a **list** as `list_nums`, take up to `n + 1` then from that return the last element which is `nth`.

```
(fn [list_nums n] (last (take (inc n) list_nums)))
```

and alternatively:

```
#(last (take (inc %2) %1))
```

proof:

```
(= (#(last (take (inc %2) %1)) '(4 5 6 7) 2) 6) ;; => true
```

Answer (score 2):

What you would really want to do is use the built-in `nth` function as it does exactly what you're asking:
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/nth

However, since you're learning this is still a good exercise.  Your code actually works for me.  Make sure you're giving it a list and not a vector -- pop does something different with vectors (it returns the vector without the last item rather than the first -- [see here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pop)).

Comment: Yes i know about the built-in nth function, but i am just exercising here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for lists if supplied index is not equal or greater then length of sequence (you've implemented zero indexed `nth`). You get this error when `tmp-list` gets empty before your `cnt` gets to the zero.

It does not work so well with vectors:

```
user> (sdsu-nth [1 2 3 4] 2)
;; => 1
user> (sdsu-nth [10 2 3 4] 2)
;; => 10
```

it seems to return `0` element for every supplied index. As noisesmith noticed it happens because `pop` works differently for vectors because of their internal structure. For vectors `pop` will remove elements form the end, and then `first` returns first value of any vector.

**How to fix:** use `rest` instead of `pop`, to remove differences in behavior of your function when applied to lists and vectors.

Comment: it will count backward from the end with vectors

Comment: @noisesmith, just tried it... it seems to return first element for any supplied index... Wait a minute..

Comment: `user> (pop [0 1 2 3 4]) => [0 1 2 3]` - using this method, you get nth item from the end, not from the beginning

Comment: oh, haha, it is mixing first and pop - it should be using first / rest or peek / pop, mixing first and pop gives absurd results

Comment: @noisesmith, you're right, but `first` is also guilty :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
(fn [xs n]
  (if (= n 0)
    (first xs)
    (recur (rest xs) (dec n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way that I thought of doing this and making it truly non recursive (ie without for/recur) is

```
(defn sdsu-nth
 [input-list n]
 (if (zero? (count input-list))
    (throw (Exception. "IndexOutOfBoundsException"))
    (if (>= n (count input-list))
       (throw (Exception. "IndexOutOfBoundsException"))
       (if (neg? n)
          (throw (Exception. "IndexOutOfBoundsException"))
          (last (take (+ n 1) input-list))))))
```

Comment: `(first (drop n input-list))` will also work, try using `cond` to eliminate chain of `if` `else` statements.